# if user_signed_in? devise doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using user_signed_in? to check if the user is logged in to display the logout link if not logged in it will display the login link, but for some reason it's only show the login link either if the user is signed in or not.
And when i click on the login link it will say the user signed in already. in this case it should display the log out link but it does not.

```
<%if user_signed_in?%>
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete%>
<%else%>
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: what about <% if current_user.present? %> ?

Comment: if the user logged in already It display the login link even and won't display the logout link.

Comment: Have you tried logging/ displaying `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` to pinpoint where the problem is? Or logged from your controller to make sure that the user is _actually_ signed in? Because chances are you've messed up some part of the login.

Comment: When i click on the login link it will say the user signed in already. in this case it should display the log out link but it does not.